Can the storage segment of an XMLTYPE column be named at will during creation?
Conversely as for LOB columns, I cannot find how to give the name I wish to the storage segment created for an XMLTYPE column within the CREATE TABLE script. Is that possible on Oracle 19c and can anybody eventually post an example?
CREATE TABLE tab (
  doc   XMLTYPE
)
XMLTYPE COLUMN (doc) STORAGE CLOB { name the storage segment tab#doc_lob } 



From the CREATE TABLE documentation:

XMLType_column_properties::=

XMLType_storage::=


Then an example of the syntax is:
CREATE TABLE tab (
  doc   XMLTYPE
)
XMLTYPE COLUMN doc STORE AS CLOB tab#doc_lob;

fiddle
